# Pip packages not showing up even after installing it on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-20.04

Have Python 3.8.10 installed in ubuntu 20.04.
I am trying to install a pip package - xmltodict

```
 sudo pip3 install xmltodict
Collecting xmltodict
  Using cached xmltodict-0.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Installing collected packages: xmltodict
Successfully installed xmltodict-0.13.0
```

However, when I am trying to use it in the Python shell, it's not showing up:

```py
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xmltodict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmltodict'
>>> exit()
```

It's not showing up when trying to perform a `pip list` or `pip show`:

```
 sudo pip3 show xmltodict
WARNING: Package(s) not found: xmltodict
```

Expected the Python package to be available after install, which is not the case.

Comment: And don't use `sudo` with `pip`, there's (practically) never a reason to.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [installation instructions](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/), there is an [official Debian package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python-xmltodict) for Debian-based distros (such as Ubuntu), which could be installed using:

```
sudo apt install python-xmltodict
```